Using Template Stages in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I am using stages from different Repository as a template Stage in my DevOps Pipeline. But I am not able to use those stages as dependsOn in a subsequent Stage. I am not allowed to make changes inside the Template Stages (build_functionapp_testcase2, datafactory_testcase3)
This is my pipeline, in this, I want that the Stage Cleanup is run if any of the above stages fail and it should also get the $NEW_VERSION variable from the 'ImageDeployment' Stage. Please help me with this.:
  - stage: ImageDeployment
    jobs:
      - job: NewImageDeployment
        timeoutInMinutes: 180
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - task: AzureKeyVault@2
            displayName: 'Fetch Secrets'
            inputs:
              connectedServiceName: '$(GLOBAL_SERVICE_CONNECTION)'
              keyVaultName: $(GLOBAL_KV_NAME)
              secretsFilter: "Packer-Secret"
              runAsPreJob: false

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Check image version'
            retryCountOnTaskFailure: 0
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(GLOBAL_SERVICE_CONNECTION)'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                while IFS=$'\t' read -a arr_image_versions; do
                  version=${arr_image_versions[0]}
                  date=${arr_image_versions[1]}
                  if [[ $date > $old_date ]]; then
                    last_version=$version
                  fi
                  old_date=$date
                done <<< "$(az sig image-version list --gallery-image-definition xxxxxxxxxxx --gallery-name xxxxxxx --resource-group xxxxxxxx --query "[].[name, publishingProfile.publishedDate]" -o tsv)"
                echo "Last image version: $last_version"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=last_version]$last_version"
            
          - task: Bash@3
            name: CheckImageVersion
            displayName: 'Increment image version'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                IFS='.' read -ra VERSION_PARTS <<< "$(last_version)"
                PATCH_VERSION=${VERSION_PARTS[2]}
                PATCH_VERSION=$((PATCH_VERSION + 1))
                NEW_VERSION="${VERSION_PARTS[0]}.${VERSION_PARTS[1]}.$PATCH_VERSION"
                echo "New image version: $NEW_VERSION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION;isOutput=true]$NEW_VERSION"

  - template: tests/build_functionapp_testcase2.yaml@self

  - template: tests/datafactory_testcase3.yaml@self

  - stage: Cleanup
    dependsOn: ImageDeployment
    condition: failed()
    jobs:
      - job: DeleteImage
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        variables:
          NEW_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.ImageDeployment.NewImageDeployment.outputs['CheckImageVersion.NEW_VERSION'] ]
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "NEW_VERSION in Cleanup stage: $(NEW_VERSION)" ```


Please try with the suggestion in my answer. @SumitBhardwaj

On the "Cleanup" stage, you can directly provide a list of stage names to the "dependsOn" option.
stages:
- stage: ImageDeployment

. . .
# Some stages defined in templates.
. . .

- stage: Cleanup
  dependsOn:
    - ImageDeployment
    - <name of stage_1 defined in templates>
    - <name of stage_2 defined in templates>
    . . .
    - <name of stage_N defined in templates>
  condition: failed()

With above configurations, when any of the listed stages is failed, the "Cleanup" stage will run, and it also can get the output variable from "ImageDeployment" stage.

I underestand but I am using a reusable Template as a Stage (build_functionapp_testcase2.yaml and datafactory_testcase3.yaml ) and I cannot assign a name to it so How can I use it in dependsOn for the Cleanup Stage?

@SumitBhardwaj, The stage names should have been defined in the templates (- stage: <name-of-stage>), just like you defined the stage names "ImageDeployment" and "Cleanup". You just need to copy the names from the templates to the "dependsOn" option of "Cleanup" stage.

yes, you are right. I did not think of that. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Stage conditions

I want that the Stage Cleanup is run if any of the above stages fail

You can use a combination of or(..) and failed(STAGE_NAME) expressions such as:
- stage: Cleanup
  condition: or(
      failed('ImageDeployment'),
      failed('testcase2_STAGE_NAME'),
      failed('testcase3_STAGE_NAME')
    )
  jobs:
  - job: DeleteImage
    steps:
    # ...

Stage dependencies

But I am not able to use those stages as dependsOn in a subsequent Stage.

TL;DR ideally a parameter should be added to the stage templates; if that's not an option, keep in mind that when you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run one after the other.
Creating configurable/extensible templates
Considering that it's difficult to predict and understand all the scenarios in which a stage or job template will be used, in order to create configurable and extensible stages/jobs templates the template authors/maintainers should be add some parameters to these templates, in order to:

Set stage/job condition
Set stage/job dependencies
Set job timeout
...

For example:
# templates/my-stage.yaml

parameters:  
  # other parameters here

  - name: dependsOn
    type: object
    displayName: 'Dependencies'
    default: []

  - name: condition
    type: string
    displayName: 'Condition'
    default: ''

stages:
  - stage: my_stage
    displayName: My stage
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
    ${{ if ne(parameters.condition, '') }}:
      condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}
    jobs:
      # ...


Yes, but I want that the Stage Cleanup is run if any of the above stages fail and it should also get the $NEW_VERSION variable from the 'ImageDeployment' Stage. How do I do that?

@SumitBhardwaj updated my answer. You can set a condition or some code to validate the value of variable NEW_VERSION in job DeleteImage.

I underestand but I am using a reusable Template as a Stage (build_functionapp_testcase2.yaml and datafactory_testcase3.yaml ) and I cannot assign a name to it so How can I use it in dependsOn for the Cleanup Stage?

@SumitBhardwaj stages have a name - if you can't set one, go to the source code of the templates and check which name is assigned. Otherwise, ask it to the templates authors/maintainers. Without it it's probably not possible to do the things you want.
